# Nest Ember Helper within Handlebar

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, helper

I am trying to embed a helper within the handlebars of a piece of my app. Everything with the helper works when I test it outside of the handlebar, but when I try to move it within it does not work. This is the code I have:

```
  {{ember-progress-bar  progress="{{sum model.points 1200}}"}}
```

Does anyone know how I am suppose to properly nest the progress helper?

Answer (score 2):

Use `()`.

```
{{ember-progress-bar  progress=(sum model.points 1200)}}
```

Reference:
https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/templates/handlebars-basics/#toc_nested-helpers

Comment: That works if I use two numbers, but the model.points is not coming in now. Any thoughts?

Comment: model.points is not visible in that context. you can verify it using `{{log 'model.points' model.points}}`

Comment: Where are you including `ember-progress-bar` ?.if you are including it in template then the route file and corresponding controller code is required to identify the issue